# Line features into polygon features

Tags: arcgis-10.0, polygon, line, arctoolbox, geometry-conversion

Can any one tell me how to convert line features into polygon features in ArcGIS.  I am using ArcGIS 10. I searched the arc toolbox for any tools for this conversion, but I couldn't find any.  Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Have you looked at Feature to Polygon? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003n000000

Comment: Construct Polygons in Topology toolbar can also help you http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t0000007r000000.htm